# 心を鬼にする >>What's the meaning of this expression ? (I've decided to become ruthless /evil ?)

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

**心を鬼にする** >> Can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of this expression ?

I guess it's like "I've made up my mind to become ruthless (though I don't want to) "?

I'm not so sure so can anyone give me a correct understanding thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess isn't too far off the mark.  A more idiomatic way of saying that in English is *"to harden one's heart"*, generally in reference to when you need to do something that someone doesn't want you to do, but that might actually be good for that person.

As explained in my personal copy of Daijirin:

> **[心]{こころ}を[鬼]{おに}にする**
> 気の毒に思いながら，その人のためを思ってやむなく厳しくする。「―＿して破門する」

Relevant entries in [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BF%83%E3%82%92%E9%AC%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-500530) (all in Japanese), and in [bilingual Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BF%83%E3%82%92%E9%AC%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B).

Comment: can I understand it as "I steel myself /my heart " ?

Comment: @4chanuser, there's a difference in nuance.  _Steel oneself_ sounds more like someone is doing something that they really don't want to do, that they find frightening or unnerving or anxiety-producing.  I may _steel myself_ before going bungie jumping, for instance.  Meanwhile, _harden one's heart_ sounds more like someone is doing something that affects someone else in a way that the doer of the action feels sympathy or empathy for the other person.  I may _harden my heart_ before I have to tell someone bad news that they need to hear, for instance.

Comment: thanks for your detail answer o/